# Selecting polygons that are to left (in west) of point in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, select-by-location

I am working with ArcMap 10.3 and I have to select polygons that are left (in the west) of a point layer. I want to try it with "select by location" but I am not sure if that is really possible.

Is there a way that I can handle this in ArcMap?

Comment: What does the data look like? what CRS? what is the extent of it?  Also you say west of a point, is this point always the same or is it arbitrary?

Comment: Use add geometry attributes (extent) tool on polygons. One of attributes added is going to be xmax. Use same tool on point. It will give you pointX. Use select by attributes to find out polygons where xmax<pointX.

Comment: Projected Coordinate System: MGI_M31
Projection: Transverse_Mercator
the point is always the same

Comment: i'll try it with the attributes....
thanks for the help, both of you :-)